# sending data from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, python-2.7, cgi

**I'm trying to send the tweets fetched by the the tweepy to javascript and later to be displayed on a page.What code should be in python script to send data to javascript and also in the javascript to receive data send by the python 
  (ignore the print(s) those are for testing)**

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe         
import json       
import urllib2      
import cgi      
import cgitb    
import re    
import tweepy      
import sys  
from tweepy import OAuthHandler    

from textblob import TextBlob          
cgitb.enable()    
request = json.load(sys.stdin)    
print"Content-Type: application/json\n"  
print"/n"    

print "Content-type: text/html\n"  
print " \n"
class TwitterClient(object):
'''
Generic Twitter Class for sentiment analysis.
'''

def __init__(self):
    '''
    Class constructor or initialization method.
    '''
    # keys and tokens from the Twitter Dev Console
    consumer_key = '6np6r6TPspLKLsl0UukYpc2YU'
    consumer_secret = 'twRMcga6wygBlls2naBIxrGK91akB9W6P5o3uiPBj6nzry0yRu'
    access_token = '3278465078-3ZGHyvElbZMzcuugAdxlYb5IP0iNI5DFf2Ng37h'
    access_token_secret = 'flFWQH9m07rNNoxHy7sxsWa6XZIx9s2zMyZuv9C1N6Gld'

    # attempt authentication
    try:
        # create OAuthHandler object
        self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        # set access token and secret
        self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        # create tweepy API object to fetch tweets
        self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)
    except:
        print("Error: Authentication Failed")

def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
    '''
    Utility function to clean tweet text by removing links, special characters
    using simple regex statements.
    '''
    return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])| (\w +:\ / \ / \S +)", " ", tweet).split())

def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet):
    '''
    Utility function to classify sentiment of passed tweet
    using textblob's sentiment method
    '''
    # create TextBlob object of passed tweet text
    analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet))
    # set sentiment
    if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
        return 'positive'
    elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
        return 'neutral'
    else:
        return 'negative'

def get_tweets(self, query, count=10):
    '''
    Main function to fetch tweets and parse them.
    '''
    # empty list to store parsed tweets
    tweets = []

    try:
        # call twitter api to fetch tweets
        fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q=query, count=count)

        # parsing tweets one by one
        for tweet in fetched_tweets:
            # empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet
            parsed_tweet = {}

            # saving text of tweet
            parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text
            # saving sentiment of tweet
            parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)

            # appending parsed tweet to tweets list
            if tweet.retweet_count > 0:
                # if tweet has retweets, ensure that it is appended only once
                if parsed_tweet not in tweets:
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
            else:
                tweets.append(parsed_tweet)

        # return parsed tweets
        return tweets

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        # print error (if any)
        print("Error : " + str(e))

def main(): 
api=TwitterClient()


tweets = api.get_tweets(query=request['input'], count=request['count'])  

# picking positive tweets from tweets
ptweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive']
# percentage of positive tweets
print("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100 * len(ptweets) / len(tweets)))
print("<br>")
print("<br>")
# picking negative tweets from tweets
ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative']
# percentage of negative tweets
print("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100 * len(ntweets) / len(tweets)))
print("<br>")
print("<br>")
# percentage of neutral tweets
x = len(tweets)
y = len(ntweets)
z = len(ptweets)
l = x - (y+z)
print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} % ".format(100 * l / len(tweets)))
print("<br>")
print("<br>")
# printing first 5 positive tweets
print("<br>")
print("<br>")
print("\n\nPositive tweets:")
print("<br>")
print("<br>")

for tweet in ptweets[:10]:
    print(tweet['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
    print("<br>")
    print("<br>")

# printing first 5 negative tweets
print("\n\nNegative tweets:")
for tweet in ntweets[:10]:
    print(tweet['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
    print("<br>")
    print("<br>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # calling main function
        main()
```

Comment: What issue are you having requesting data from `python` script?

Comment: @guest271314 The issue is ,I don't know how to proceed,the data is fetched by the python script ,now how to send it to the javascript ?

Comment: Request the data from `python` script

Comment: @guest271314 here  is the link to javascript code:[link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/mac5p)  . How to get response from python script?

Comment: Not sure about `python` portion of code. Where does code expect a request and serve a response?